# How to scrollTo Flatlist ListHeaderComponent top?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have Flatlist with ListHeaderComponent. The content of ListHeaderComponent is a little big. I want to scroll up of the screen. How can I achieve with Flatlist? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by  creating a ref in Flatlist by below :

```
 <FlatList
          horizontal={true}
          data={this.props.activeUsersList ? this.props.activeUsersList : []}
          renderItem={({item, index}) => {
            return this.renderUsername(item, index);
          }}
          ref={ref => {
            this.flatListRef = ref;
          }}
        />
```

and then in the below you can call this anywhere and it will scroll to top,

```
this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: 0});
```

hopeit helps. feel free for doubts

Answer (score 0):

You can use ref in FlatList to scroll to top or bottom.

If you want to Scroll Flatlist to Top. You can use -

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.messages}
    renderItem={({ item }, index) => this.messageDisplay(item, index)}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    ref={(ref) => (this.flatList = ref)}
    onContentSizeChange={ () => this.flatList.scrollToIndex({ animated: true }) }
    onLayout={ () => this.flatList.scrollToIndex({ animated: true }) }
/>
```

***Here, data is stored in `this.state.messages` and the renderItem Function is `messageDisplay`***

If you want to Scroll Flatlist to bottom. You can use -

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.messages}
    renderItem={({ item }, index) => this.messageDisplay(item, index)}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    ref={(ref) => (this.flatList = ref)}
    onContentSizeChange={ () => this.flatList.scrollToEnd({ animated: true }) }
    onLayout={ () => this.flatList.scrollToEnd({ animated: true }) }
/>
```

I hope this helps.